# Has anyone tried to do a PS script to upload CSV files to BigQuery?

Tags: powershell

I was able to create a python script to upload files to Bigquery, but has anyone tried it with Powershell ?

I tried to find an API call for PS but I cannot find anything

Comment: Quick and easy CSV file loader to bigquery for the community you will need a SVC account linked to your bq project.

Authentication
gcloud auth activate-service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT@EMAIL>COM --key-JSON FILE WITH THE SVC_ACCOUNT

BigQuery CSV files loader
bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 DATASET.TABLE_NAME CSVFILE.CSV

Thanks guys!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and easy CSV file loader to bigquery for the community
you will need a SVC account linked to your bq project.

## Authentication

gcloud auth activate-service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT@EMAIL>COM --key-JSON FILE WITH THE SVC_ACCOUNT

## BigQuery CSV files loader

bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1  DATASET.TABLE_NAME CSVFILE.CSV

Thanks guys!

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Yea, there are a few ways...

1. [Use the Google Cloud Tools for Powershell](https://cloud.google.com/tools/powershell/docs/bigquery) (this is in beta)
2. [Load data using BigQuery's web API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/)
3. [Load data using the .Net client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries)

Option-1 is probably your best bet. Checkout `Add-BqTableRow`:

```
Add-BqTableRow takes CSV, JSON, and AVRO files to import into BigQuery.
```

Option-3: You'll find the .Net examples will mostly be in C#. Convert what you see to Powershell.